# Fix git history with duplicate commits

Tags: git

Short version:
How do I go from the left graph to the right one. Also, do I need to manually clear the duplicate commits (root2, a', b') or the GC will prune them at some point in the future?
[image: before-after]

Long version:
Due to a bad CVS to git port I ended up with two alternate histories in the same repo when I imported branch_1 from CVS when master had been already created in git. As can be seen, there are commits of branch_1 that are unique, but there are others that are duplicates. What is the easiest way to fix this?

I have some ideas but not sure how to execute them. One would be to remove branch_1 altogether and start again, but I don't know how to make git recognize that `root1` and `root2` are the same so that all patches get applied on the same line. Another idea would be to rebase *f, g, h* onto *b* and somehow remove *root2, a'* and *b'*. But I think that since there is no common ancestor, a normal rebase will not work

In reality, the duplicate commits and unique commits of the branch are hundreds so something very manual is not good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the rebase you are asking for will rewrite the commit hashes of *all* commits on `branch_1`. I am using `b` and `b'` to indicate the commit hashes of the commits in your beautiful figure.

```
git checkout branch_1
git rebase --onto b b'
```

This matches the following form of `git rebase` from the manual page:

```
git rebase --onto <newbase> <upstream>
```

Based on the manual, the following will then happen.

1. All changes made by commits in the current branch but that are not in `<upstream>` are saved to a temporary area.
2. The current branch is reset to `<upstream>`, or `<newbase>` if the `--onto` option was supplied.
3. The commits that were previously saved into the temporary area are then reapplied to the current branch, one by one, in order.

Comment: IIUC, the way rebases work is by replaying commits in the current branche since the **last common ancestor** between the two branches. In my case there is no common ancestor. So either it will fail or it will put *root2* as a child of *b*. Either case is wrong. Am i missing something?

Comment: @Hilikus, Look at `man git-rebase` and grep for the `--onto` option.

Comment: will i need to manipulate the repo to remove the duplicate commits or the fact that they are dangling means they will be at some point GC'd? i'm not very clear on whether commits live forever on a repo or if they need to be reachable for them to live forever

Comment: Dangling commits will always be garbage collected eventually

Comment: If there is any difference at all between the `b` and `b'` trees, this will remove that difference, which could cause you to lose data.  For that reason, I recommend using grafts instead, as in pioto's answer.  Fundamentally, `git rebase` is performing a merge operation and then rewriting it without the merge, whereas a graft point avoids the merge operation entirely.  There's nothing inherently wrong with `git rebase`, it's just that grafts do exactly what you want here.

Comment: @dietrichepp while I agree with you in general the op stated that he's is trying to kill **duplicate** commits.

Comment: Right... but if, due to any mistake, they're not duplicate commits, tree data could be lost with a rebase.  This is *exactly* the kind of problem that grafts are suited to solve: you have the wrong history, so you graft your commits onto the correct history.  Rebase is designed to solve a different problem: you have commits on the wrong branch.  In this case the branch is correct, but the branch's history is wrong.

Comment: They are different ways to see the same thing.  I don't disagree with you.

Answer (score 2):

One option you can try first, which is non-destructive, is to use a [Graft Point](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GraftPoint):

```
# .git/info/grafts
0000000f 0000000b
```

Replace those with the SHA1s of commit `f` and `b` in your diagram.

This change will be non-permanent, but should be able to reviewed with:

```
git log --graph --all --decorate
```

If all looks good, you can run [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) to make those changes permanent.

Note that, until you do a `git filter-branch` and push that, nobody else will see these changes. This could be considered a "feature", since it won't force anyone else to have to do a messy rebase of their work. This basically just adds some extra information that tells tools like git-log and such that, when they look at commit "f", they should pretend it has a parent of "b", without actually updating the commit object to reflect that. Changing the parent of a commit object changes its SHA1, so that means that its child commits need to be updated to point to the new SHA1, and then their children, etc.

Comment: I recommend this over `git rebase` because it preserves the contents (trees) of both branches.  `git rebase` preserves the changes (diffs).

Comment: @DietrichEpp you mean that i will end up with the left graph but with an extra edge from `b` to `f`? If that's what you mean by "preserves the trees", i don't want that since both of those trees are really duplicates

Comment: No, you basically end up with the graph on the right, but it does it without rewriting any of your history.

Comment: @Hilikus: You end up with the picture on the right, except instead of f, g, h, I'd label them f', g', h', since they'll have different commit hashes.  You still rewrite history, you just don't change any of the tree contents.  You can delete the `grafts` file after you rewrite history.